# MS CRM What is the difference between [dbo].[Entity].[IsAudited] and [dbo].[Entity].[IsAuditEnabled]?

Tags: dynamics-crm

I want to filter entities where exists data in [dbo].[AuditBase]. I have found these fields but don't understand it's sense. Provide to me the information, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IsAudited** 
This represents whether or not the entity can be audited.  As a general rule normal entities can be audited, while certain system entities and bridge entities for N:N relationships cannot be audited.  For example, contacts and activities can be audited, while attachments cannot.

**IsAuditEnabled**
This represents whether or not auditing has been turned on for the entity.

If IsAudited = 0 then there will be no audit records in the AuditBase table for that entity.  If IsAudited = 1 then there may be audit records, even if IsAuditEnabled = 0 since at some point in the past auditing may have been enabled and then turned off.